# Meteor HCP does not update Androind Apps

Tags: cordova, meteor

I am on Meteor 1.8.1. I have an android app which has a public folder full of content. A server is running the server build. I change the content in the public folder and expect HCP to update the app with the new content when app is reloaded. But I can see the update is only visible when I browse the server URL from browser. Apps never update. Uninstall, Installing the app does not help either.

Looking at the logs, these three lines seems to be telling that a new version is detected. But the new version isn't shown:

```
08-19 16:07:16.775 24331 24331 W MeteorWebApp: Loading asset bundle from directory file:///android_asset/www/application
08-19 16:07:16.814 24331 24331 D MeteorWebApp: Initial bundle loaded dcbda88356768b5995eb01252953c33e8792f5ab
08-19 16:07:16.815 24331 24331 D MeteorWebApp: Detected new bundled version, removing versions directory if it exists
```

I can see some log entries that looks like some problem with Cordova bundle:

```
08-19 15:47:36.164 21426 21482 W MeteorWebApp: Asset /__cordova/a8716fc383e1d6798d1d2f74c7a1efa133561b90.css found in bundle d4ab999152177e0d1f69c80d5554edcf22bac01a:file:///android_asset/www/application
08-19 15:47:36.168 21426 21482 W MeteorWebApp: Asset /cordova.js not found in bundle d4ab999152177e0d1f69c80d5554edcf22bac01a:file:///android_asset/www/application, no parent bundle
08-19 15:47:36.172 21426 21482 W MeteorWebApp: Asset /__cordova/93384f261c67033d275f67c41bf561bee6406478.js found in bundle d4ab999152177e0d1f69c80d5554edcf22bac01a:file:///android_asset/www/application
08-19 15:47:36.245 21426 21482 W MeteorWebApp: Asset /cordova_plugins.js not found in bundle d4ab999152177e0d1f69c80d5554edcf22bac01a:file:///android_asset/www/application, no parent bundle
08-19 15:47:36.256 21426 21482 W MeteorWebApp: Asset /plugins/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp/www/webapp_local_server.js not found in bundle d4ab999152177e0d1f69c80d5554edcf22bac01a:file:///android_asset/www/application, no parent bundle
```

I have tried manually calling WebAppLocalServer.checkForUpdates(); on Meteor.startup, but I can see this exception:

```
08-19 16:07:19.368 24331 24445 W MeteorWebApp: Download failure
08-19 16:07:19.368 24331 24445 W MeteorWebApp: com.meteor.webapp.WebAppException: Error parsing asset manifest
08-19 16:07:19.368 24331 24445 W MeteorWebApp:  at com.meteor.webapp.AssetManifest.<init>(AssetManifest.java:80)
08-19 16:07:19.368 24331 24445 W MeteorWebApp:  at com.meteor.webapp.AssetBundleManager$1.onResponse(AssetBundleManager.java:112)
08-19 16:07:19.368 24331 24445 W MeteorWebApp:  at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:153)
08-19 16:07:19.368 24331 24445 W MeteorWebApp:  at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
08-19 16:07:19.368 24331 24445 W MeteorWebApp:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
08-19 16:07:19.368 24331 24445 W MeteorWebApp:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
08-19 16:07:19.368 24331 24445 W MeteorWebApp:  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
08-19 16:07:19.368 24331 24445 W MeteorWebApp: Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

I have confirmed the server is running and the app is successfully able to make calls to the server. There are some plugins in the app like OneSignal, ostrio:logger that are able to successfully communicate with the server. Only the HCP isn't working.

UPDATE

After adding the cordova platform, the __cordova/manifest.json endpoint is generated. However, the app and server gets built with differnt App ID. As a result, HCP does not work throwing App ID mismatch exception. I was able to fix the App ID on the server by setting APP_ID environment variable. But can't find a way to set the App ID on the mobile build. Preparing a mobile-config.js and passing it as --mobile-settings parameter in the meteor build command does not work either. It fails at the cordova build step saying the file is invalid. The file is definitely valid as it worked till Meteor version 1.4. But after upgrading to Meteor 1.8.1, it started failing.

Comment: Are you using a package(mdg:reload-on-resume) or do you have code to control HCP? As of meteor 1.8.1 you must call WebAppLocalServer.switchToPendingVersion(); before reloading the page or the HCP won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I found that the android platform wasn't added on the server. after adding the platform, it started generating the __cordova/manifest.json endpoint. But now I have different problem. The meteor build command is generating app with unique ID each time. As a result, it does not match with the appID of the server.

Comment: Are you using --debug flag when doing the android build?

Comment: No, I am not. Just regular build command.

Comment: have you configured the mobile-config.js file?
https://docs.meteor.com/api/mobile-config.html

Comment: have you defined METEOR_CORDOVA_COMPAT_VERSION_IOS and METEOR_CORDOVA_COMPAT_VERSION_ANDROID? This forces those values to be the same, even if your plugins change. You can also look for these values to see what they currently are, and whether they are changing each time in __cordova/manifest.json. If you set these, then you can call your build like this:  METEOR_CORDOVA_COMPAT_VERSION_IOS=(some value you like) METEOR_CORDOVA_COMPAT_VERSION_ANDROID=(that value again) meteor build (... the rest of your build command)